# How to get additional attribute value of product from Magento using SOAP APIin c# windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, magento

I am having a problem while exporting sales orders from magento using SOAP API in a C# Windows application.  I could get all data from magento but I cant get Magento product addtional attribute value if that product SKU value is an integer.  I can get  that additional attribute value if the SKU is a string.  My client requirement is to get addtional attribute value of the product with integer SKU value.

my code is

```
itemSKU = salesOrderInfo.items[j].sku;
productId = salesOrderInfo.items[j].product_id;
catalogProductRequestAttributes catalogProductRequest = new catalogProductRequestAttributes();

catalogProductRequest.additional_attributes = new string[] { "quickbooks_stock_category" };

catalogProductReturnEntity catalogProductReturn = magentoservice.catalogProductInfo(result,itemSKU, "default", catalogProductRequest, null);

associativeEntity[] associative = catalogProductReturn.additional_attributes;

string quickbooksItemName = associative[0].value;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: hi i solved this problem my it self.I tried with ProductID in the catalogProductInfo API instead of giving itemSKU .It is working fine now for both integer and String SKU